# Gmaps does not show up in Spyder

Tags: google-maps, anaconda, spyder, python-3.7

I am running a simple example:

```
import gmaps
import gmaps.datasets

gmaps.configure(api_key="...")
earthquake_df = gmaps.datasets.load_dataset_as_df( 'earthquakes' ) 
locations = earthquake_df[[ 'latitude' , 'longitude' ]] 
weights = earthquake_df[ 'magnitude' ] 
fig = gmaps.figure() 
fig.add_layer(gmaps.heatmap_layer(locations, weights=weights)) 
fig
```

but instead of seeing a heatmap, the output shows this:

```
Figure(layout=FigureLayout(height='420px'))
```

I am using Spyder (Python 3.7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) The reason is very simple: Spyder can't show web content on its consoles. By web content I mean content that can only be rendered in a web browser. and that's the case for the `gmaps` package.

Comment: I see. Is there a way around this? Also why am I being downvoted here? Is this a bad question?

Comment: No, there's no workaround right now. And you probably got downvoted because your question was not clear enough to other people.

Comment: I'm using folium instead now. It doesn't render too. But at least I can export it as html .

Comment: @CarlosCordoba Is there any alternative to ```gmaps``` package to get google maps, that is working in Spyder?

Comment: @MariuszSiatka, I don't think so. However, we're planning to add a viewer for web content on Spyder 5 (to be released in 2020), that should fix this problem.