# Display google map or gmaps in python IDE (pycharm)

Tags: python-3.x, google-maps, pycharm, gmaps.js

I'm working on gmaps in python and I want to display the result.

```
import gmaps.datasets
gmaps.configure(api_key='***')
# Latitude-longitude pairs
geneva = (46.2, 6.1)
montreux = (46.4, 6.9)
zurich = (47.4, 8.5)
fig = gmaps.figure()
geneva2zurich = gmaps.directions_layer(geneva, zurich)
fig.add_layer(geneva2zurich)
fig
```

It seems like it works well in Jupyter, but in pycharm it displays nothing.

Why this happens? How can I export the result?

Comment: You published your API_KEY.

Answer (score 0):

a Spyder maintainer said on one post that in a Spyder IDE the gmaps doesn't display the map. So, I think is the same problem with Pycharm. It only displays maps using jupyter.
You can check the answer on this link: [Gmaps does not show up in Spyder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55138615/gmaps-does-not-show-up-in-spyder)